# Does NGINX handle some error events / codes without them being set up in the config by default?

Tags: nginx

**Question:** Are there some error events / codes that NGINX handles by default?

**Background:** The following portion of my config stops hotlinking and returns a 403 error.

```
    location ~* \.(jpg|png|svg|webp|ico)$ {
        valid_referers none blocked server_names ~\.bing\. ~\.duckduckgo\. ~\.facebook\. ~\.google\. ~\.instagram\. ~\.twitter\. ~\.yahoo\.;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return 403;
        }
    }
```

This section blocks unwanted HTTP methods and returns a 405 error.

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
    return 405;
}
```

This got me thinking, are there any errors that I don't have to set up in NGINX?

For example, a [400 Bad Request error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). Does NGINX know what a bad request is without adding an `if` statement and some logic to the config?

Alternately do I need to set up every error in the config that I plan to use and if I don't it can't be triggered? I always assumed this was the case but when I see how many different 400 and 500 errors there are I wonder if I'm not fully understanding this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx will handle everything except application level errors. A few examples would be

400 if the request breaks RFC specified format.
403 if nginx cannot read a file due to permission.
404 if the file isn't found.

And so on so forth, the only thing nginx doesn't handle is non-RFC requirements like your anti-hotlinking and things outside its scope such as fastcgi/uwsgi/http backends.

Basically don't worry about anything not related to your specific business logic.

Comment: Awesome!  On the 400 error example do I still need to include a location in my config so that when NGINX sees the error it knows what to send?  For example, `error_page 400 /html/400.html;`

Comment: It has a simple default error page, see here: https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+400+example&tbm=isch

You can customise it to look nicer yes, but it's not required.